# Sort javascript object by some of the keys

Tags: javascript

How can I sort an array of objects that looks like that:

```
 data = [{'Name': 'Peter', 'Chemistry': 10, 'Math': 9, 'Geography': 5},
         {'Name': 'Bob', 'Math': 6, 'Chemistry': 10, 'Geography': 5}]
```

by course name only. Hence, it will look like

```
 data = [{'Name': 'Peter', 'Chemistry': 10, 'Geography': 5, 'Math': 9,},
         {'Name': 'Bob', 'Chemistry': 10, 'Geography': 5, 'Math': 6, }]
```

Comment: You can't sort the keys of an object.

Comment: No you can't sort them, you can only sort by `alphabetic ( A to Z )` or ascending order you can [read this](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/)

Comment: There is not guarantee of keys object.

Comment: to be able to change keys order use `Map` instead of object

Comment: An object is a member of the type Object. It is an _unordered_ collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function.

Comment: Although [properties do have order now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties), *using* that order is almost never what you want. (@Andy)

Comment: @Walk - Not anymore (see above; not that using the order is a good idea). :-)

Comment: @Aenaon Go through this how you can use `Map();` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056250/how-can-we-custom-sort-javascript-object-keys

Comment: um can I know why u need to sort them because you can just change your logic like for eg( console.log(obj.name,obj.chemistry,obj.geography, obj.math) ), in the order you want

Comment: Guys, I dont think it is a duplicate, as you sort some of the keys and the rest are left untouched. Thanks anyway for the replies